# Cannot add event handlers to ASP. net page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio 2008 when I drag and drop asp controlXXX on aspx page. Property page for this control, does not show event handlers button. It can reappear after switching to designer view but then disappears again. [Screenshot](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/sxlodY58EHSUFtg1PZiOGw?feat=directlink) attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's annoying, but it works probably only in designer.
But you can still add event handlers manually

in html add onclick property and write name of the method

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

and in code-behind add method with two parameters of types: (object, EventArgs) like this:

```
protected void btnAddTag_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

or you can also add event handler in Page_Init method

```
btnAdd.Click+=new ImageClickEventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
```

(this will also generate automatically the method, only after += press TAB twice)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am new to asp and web development, but isn't there more events that just "click" that can be resulted in post back. How do I suppose to add them?

Comment: I mean this is such a basic functionality I am amazed it is not working.

Comment: That's unfortunatelly limitation/bug of Visual Studio. Properties windows is probably primary build to work with Designer.

Comment: I can hardly believe they meant it to work in designer only.Really annoying is that it happens on my machine only. All other developer have it working. It is terribly inconvenient. There must be something wrong with configuration.